# GqlQuery returns random results

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I'm writing a quite simple web application based on Google's Application Engine. It's the first time I'm working with Python and Google's datastore.

The application should display some questions on its home page. Those questions are stored in a table named Question.

```
class Question(db.Model):
  question_id = db.IntegerProperty()
  question = db.StringProperty()
```

The following code selects all entries of this table and commits the data to the template.

```
questions = db.GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM Question ORDER BY question_id')

# debugging loop
for question in questions:
  logging.info(questions.question_id)

template_values = {
  'questions' : questions
}
```

And finally, the template displays the questions on the index.html.

```
{% for question in questions %}
  // HTML-CODE
  {{ question.question }}
  // HTML-CODE
{% endfor %}
```

Actually, those (very basic) operations are running well but the program skips or adds questions to the list twice. This happens completely random. I even thought it might be disappeared when it didn't pop up for hours. The error must occur immediately after the GqlQuery statement as the debugging loop already indicates wrong ids.

Which question gets skipped or added is randomly as well, I can't see a pattern here. The only thing is, that it's either one question more or less than expected. It never appears that one question gets skipped and another is added twice at the same time. The table Question only contains five entries at the moment, so it's very manageable.

I hope this isn't just a result of my lack of experience. I spent days on this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding or removing questions elsewhere in your code, that could cause this seemingly erroneous behavior. By default, App Engine queries are "eventually consistent", meaning that the query will not immediately reflect the true state of the datastore. You can read more about query consistency at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Data_consistency.

As the article states, ancestor queries are strongly consistent. To do that, you'd have to put all your Questions in the same "entity group". That's easy to do, but it necessarily introduces a choke point, and it will limit the rate at which you can create or modify Questions. It would only be appropriate if you knew that Questions would be rarely changed, even if you had a huge number of users on your site.

If you don't think that this is the problem you're seeing, could you post more detail about how Questions are created / modified / deleted in your application?